# Родительский класс в CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, наследование

Как обратиться к экземпляру родительского class-а в css? Этот вопрос задан в контексте [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1263382/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E)

Answer (score 1):

Почти никак. CSS - это каскад: обратиться можно либо к дочернему элементу, либо к идущему в потоке после элемента на одном уровне вложенности.

Исключение составляет `:focus-within`:

```css
   div {
    padding: 10px;
   }
   div:focus-within {
    background: #DEF0E7;
   }
```

```html
  <form>
   <div>
    Введите ваше имя: <input name="user">
   </div>
   <p><button>Отправить</button></p>
  </form>
```